# How to Parse below data in result using Gson in spring

Tags: json, spring, gson

i am trying to get data from a server and store the response in result below

```
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("https://jira.example.com/rest/api/id",  HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>(createHeaders()), String.class);

    result = <200 OK,{
        "ipinfo": {
            "ip_address": "131.208.128.15",
            "ip_type": "Mapped",
            "Location": {
                "continent": "north america",
                "latitude": 30.1,
                "longitude": -81.714,
                "CountryData": {
                    "country": "united states",
                    "country_code": "us"
                },
                "region": "southeast",
                "StateData": {
                    "state": "florida",
                    "state_code": "fl"
                },
                "CityData": {
                    "city": "fleming island",
                    "postal_code": "32003",
                    "time_zone": -5
                }
            }
        }
    }>
```

i have tried this  but asking me to change type of result to string but if i change i will get error at `resttemplateexchange();`

```
  JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(result);
        JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
        jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("ipinfo");
```

Comment: What error do you got ?

Comment: i was asked to make the type of result to string which will create other problem for me it will ask me to change type of result from string to ResponSe ENTITY if i change the result to string type

Comment: I don't see the "ipconfig" node into your example

Comment: sorry ipinfo it was a sample from net so some typo error

Comment: Please can you paste your exchange method code ?

Comment: i want to know how to parse this type of data as in Gson only string is allowed to parse

Comment: i have edited my code please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String json = result.getBody();   

JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("ipinfo");
[...]
```